# Request to API getting truncated

Tags: api, rest

I have an Asp.net API application running on Windows data center 2019 and some of the requests for an API get truncated.  This is happening to only one of the APIs as far as I know because it’s the only one that upload big chunks of data.  All others are tiny requests.

This API takes json in the body which contains: and issue ID and a serialized image.  The largest requests size is 20mb so its not too big and most of the time they go thru fine, but sometimes the request gets chopped off at the end – sometimes a little, sometimes a lot.  Also, there is a pattern that when a request it truncated, the API returns a 500 code and the client device tries to call the API again, and often it will continue to be truncated and always in different places.

I have good visibility into this because I use a logger module that writes every request to a text file allowing me to see exactly what hits the server.

I know the device is sending a well formatted request because it would get an exception if it created bad formatted json.

Lastly, this is using SSL.

This is what a typical request looks like:

```
HEADERS
Content-Length : 7154364
Content-Type : text/plain; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding : gzip
Host : cmtafr-dev.nwis.net
User-Agent : Dart/2.17 (dart:io)
deviceid : xxxxxxx
appversion : 2.21.10
cap2.0_tokenkey : xxxxx
osversion : 15.6.1
devicebrand : IOS
devicemodel : iPhone13,4

PATH
/api/IssueController/ExecuteIssue_UploadImageV2/7acd5643-c112-4f74-9dfa-1d558ee3ae69

BODY
{"Isu_Id":"9EC539F2-ABDD-49C5-934A-FAD6371B3E9C","ImageData":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAA...  bla bla bla"}
```

Additional info:
The screenshot below shows 2 requests attempting to upload the same image.  both failed as they were truncated.  Notice the file sizes are different  -  meaning they left the device in good shape.

[image]

However, the header on both requests show the Content-Length:
16449758

```
HEADERS
Connection : keep-alive
Content-Length : **16449758**
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : */*
```

How can I possibly troubleshoot this?  I have spent hours searching and not found anything similar to this.  Most posts regarding …truncated requests/responses are application specific where a vendor replies.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Is there a response body in the 500 errors?

Comment: Yes.  there is no problem with the responses, only requests for this one API.   When the request its this endpoint/api, i get the request content and try to parse it which will fail when its truncated and throw an exception.  In the catch I return:  return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "... a custom message here ...");